# Android studio Webview inside popup Window

Tags: java, android, webview, popup

Hello Member stackover .
I programing app andoid  > i need to show (view ) web page inside popup window 
i need to view this page in beatuy design 
i used this statement but page not show and popupwindow show very small.

Mainactivity :

```
  button58.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               FragmentTransaction manger= getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        pop_web_view  pop3 =new pop_web_view();
                        pop3.show(manger,null);


            }
        });
```

popup window class :

```
public class pop_web_view extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener{
    View view;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.web_view, container, false);




         WebView   webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");

        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set width and height for dialog

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Dialog d = getDialog();
    if (d != null) {
        int width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
        int height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
        d.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        loadWebViewLoad(webView);

   private void loadWebViewLoad(WebView webview) {
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webview.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webview.loadUrl(GlobalUrl);
    }
```